# Correctly enter the site_ID using Graph SDK

Tags: sharepoint, graph, onedrive

Regarding this expression to create a folder:

POST /sites/{site-id}/drive/items/{parent-item-id}/children

What is the correct way to enter the {site-id} and the {parent-item-id}, to access a folder (eg:folder_1) in a site (eg: site1)in a domain (eg: mydomain)

I have tried:

POST /sites/mydomain/drive/items/site1/folder_1/children

POST /sites:/mydomain/site1:/drive/items/folder_1/children

and similar, with no success,

Can you help me please?

Answer (score 0):

Do a get request like this in Graph Explorer with this request:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/<host>:<server relative url>
```

Example:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/zheguo.sharepoint.com:/sites/dev
```

Then will return site Id

[image]

Update if you want to access other library folder in Graph, firstly get drive id with this endpoint:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site-id}/drives
```

[image]

Then access the specific drive folder with this endpoint:

```
  https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site-id}/drives/{drive-id}
```

Then for "parent-item-id", it's the specific folder id in document library, you can get with this endpoint:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site-id}/drives/{drive-id}/items/root:
```

Example:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/zheguo.sharepoint.com,91a47a59-db5e-4d17-a689-479ee8905533,274459c9-4c96-42bf-9b96-838ffa387aaa/drives/b!WXqkkV7bF02miUee6JBVM8lZRCeWTL9Cm5aDj_o4eqpLdqmLE2R7QosYOZt8Dyao/items/root:/
```

Then use the endpoint to create folder:

```
POST /sites/{site-id}/drives/{drive-id}/items/{parent-item-id}/children
```

Example:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/zheguo.sharepoint.com,91a47a59-db5e-4d17-a689-479ee8905533,274459c9-4c96-42bf-9b96-838ffa387aaa/drive/items/01WU7SPCC4FNS6KOYTSJFK2MUFRITF5XQL/children
```

[image]

[image]

Reference:

[Create a new folder in a drive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-post-children?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)

Answer (score 0):

THanks for the help.

Follow your steps, but In the second step, you say:

"This is the sub folder named "2019" in default Documents library:"

With this, I can acess the shared documents folder inside the site. I don't want to acess that folder. I need to acess another folder that is in the site, but not inside the share documents folder.

Any clue?

Comment: You can get all the drives with this endpoint:
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site-id}/drives

Then access specific drive with drive id:

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site-id}/drives/driveid/

Then access folder:
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site-id}/drives/driveid/items/root:/foldername